# What is the best way to set default value of Props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

There are a few props in my application which are received from the reducer-selector.

I was wondering,
should I set default values for the props at all the below mentioned places ?

1. at defaultProps
2. in reducer
3. in selector

Or should I define the default value at only 1 of these 3 places, and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advisable to set default values in only one place. Because if it is set in one place you don't have to bother again and again in different components, selectors, etc. This will also avoid bugs due to default values.

1. **at defaultProps**: If you set defaultProps you will end up setting default value in multiple components if prop is used in multiple components. If you miss, inconsistency in results shown on UI.
2. **in selector**: If you are using the same prop from a store in multiple selectors, you have to set the default value before returning the result. Again not a good approach.
3. **in reducer**: This is the place from where the prop will be set in store. Once you set default value, it will be used across all components, selectors without any change.

I think, Setting in reduce looks more promising and stable approach considering an extensible App.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the context.
I would recommend using ES6 default parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

e.g.

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  const { name = 'default name' } = props;

  return (
    <>
     {name}
    </>
  )
}
```

The same principle applies to your reducers:

e.g.

```js
function myReducer(state = { name: 'default name' }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {}
}
```

This method works for all functions.
Alternatively, you could also use `Component.defaultProps` for React components.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware about these methods. 
But, what I am suggesting / asking is : if we just set the default value
(here 'default name') in reducer and avoid giving default values in selector and in the defaultProps,
will that be a good idea ?

Comment: I would try to keep them separate. In the best case, your component does not know about any state/logic. Therefore I would rather define them twice (e.g. reducer AND component). This way you can move them around and add dedicated unit tests. Otherwise, it is a composition for which you need an integration test because they depend on each other

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have the default prop setup only at one common place and not everywhere in your code as it will be difficult to maintain if you have to change the logic in the future.

Having the default value in the selector gives you an advantage that you don't have to worry about values resetting in the reducer for each and every update as well as you can memoize use the value.